# Manual and automated testing to validate word font size (IOS and Android)

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to perform a manual test validating the font size of the words on a given screen. It would be Mobile test (IOS and Android).

Could anyone indicate any tool that has this functionality?

And automated testing? Can Selenium (Eclipse) do this kind of validation? Currently i use character validation only (length).

I look forward and thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking length is (at least may be) unit test (just logic)

if you want to test how your view looks then you need to write UI/UX test. For that purpose I would recommend [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) and something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.textview_to_check)).perform(
     new MeasureTextSizeAction());
```

and

```
public class MeasureTextSizeAction implements ViewAction {

    public MeasureTextSizeAction() {
    }

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return isDisplayed();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "measuring TextView";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, final View view) {
        checkArgument(view instanceof TextView);
        float textSize = ((TextView) view).getTextSize();
        // validate
    }

}
```